# How to make ajax call, which has php query if i have multiple buttons with different classes

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, select

I dont know if i am asking this correctly, but i will try:

for example, i have 5 buttons, each of them has different classes.

```
<button class="table1">Table1</button>
<button class="table2">Table2</button>
// etc... //
```

I have script, which initiate ajax call if button is clicked:

```
$(".table1").click(function(){
  $.ajax({url:"test.php",success:function(result){
  $(".result").html(result);
  }});
});
```

And i have php script, which should select table by clicked button class (this is my problem):

```
foreach($db->query('SELECT * FROM table1') as $row) {
  echo '<div><b>'.$row['info1'].'</b></div>';
  echo '<span>'.$row['info2'].'</span><br/>';
  echo '<span>'.$row['info3'].'</span>';
  echo '<br/><br/><br/>';

}
```

**Problem:**
This all scripts are working, however, somehow i need to do, that if i am clicking table1, than php query should select table1, if clicking table2, than query should select table2 ...etc.

I am not good with ajax. I know only php basics.

Sorry for bad english.

Comment: Why not create a generic function that takes care of the AJAX request and accepts the target table as one of its parameters?  On the server side you could sanitize/validate the incoming information and process accordingly.

Comment: Well, that sounds great. That sounds great for more experienced programmers. I have no clue how to do that.

Comment: Take a look at @MarkB answer below.  That should be a good start.  Functions are one of the building blocks of programming.  You will save yourself a lot of time and frustration educating yourself how to use them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split your CSS classes, e.g.

```
<button class="clickable" data-tableid="1">...</button>
<button class="clickable" data-tableid="2">...</button>
```

and then attach your click handle to the `.clickable` class only. The click event will include WHICH element was clicked on, and from that you can extract the data attribute of that particular button:

```
$('.clickable').click(function(e) {  // 'e' is the click event
    sourceElement = e.target; // get the button which was clicked
    tableid = sourceElement.dataset.tableid; // extract its tableid data attribute
    ... ajax call here ...
});
```

Comment: I love the use of a `data-*` attribute here to store the row ID; a very nice pattern for exposing this kind of data or metadata.

Comment: I just need to copy my ajax script to your script? How about php? Should i use GET function?

Comment: you'd still need to actually pass the table ID on to the server somehow, e.g. `url:"test.php?tableID=" + tableid`. but basically, yes.

Answer (score 3):

I recomend modify HTML:

```
<button id="table1" class="table">Table1</button>
<button id="table2" class="table">Table2</button>
```

and javascript code:

```
$(".table").click(function(e){
  $.ajax({url:"test.php?table=" + $(e.target).attr('id'),success:function(result){
  $(".result").html(result);
  }});
});
```

Then you can check clicked table in PHP from $_GET['table'] variable.

Answer (score 0):

**Just copy,paste an run this code**

in index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"         "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

 <button id="table1" class="table">Table1</button>
 <button id="table2" class="table">Table2</button>
 <button id="table3" class="table">Table3</button>
 <script>

 $( ".table" ).click(function() {
var table = $(this).attr('id');
$.ajax({//create an ajax request to load_page.php
type: "POST",
url: "sample.php",
data:{"data":table},
success: function(data) {
    if (data) {

       alert(data);
    }
    else {
        alert('Successfully not posted.');
    }
}
});
}); 
</script>


  </body>
  </html>
```

in sample.php

```
<?php
        if(isset($_POST['data'])){
        $table = $_POST['data'];
        foreach($db->query("SELECT * FROM '$table'") as $row) {
        echo $db->query("SELECT * FROM '$table'");
        echo '<div><b>'.$row['info1'].'</b></div>';
        echo '<span>'.$row['info2'].'</span><br/>';
        echo '<span>'.$row['info3'].'</span>';
        echo '<br/><br/><br/>';

      }
      }
    ?>
```